# Trying to evaluate pi to 7s.f. using a the result from Taylor Series approximation from arctan(x). Struggling with the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, equation

I'm completely new to Python and am having a little trouble with a part of my assignment.

Firstly, we had to define a function that would approximate arctan(x) using a Taylor series expansion.

Now, I have to use the fact that arctan(1) = pi/4 to evaluate pi to 7sf using my function, and find the number of iterations N required for this level of accuracy.

Here is my code for my Taylor Expansion (the conditional statement is there for another part of the assignment):

```
import math as mt


def TaylorExp (x,N):
    if abs(x) <=1:
            n=0.0
            total = 0.0
            while (n<N): #performs N iterations.
                c = (((-1)**n)/((2*n)+1))*(x**((2*n)+1))
                total += c
                n += 1    
            return total
```

and here is my code for attempting to evaluate pi to 7sf and find N required:

```
i=0
z = 0
k=0
while ((format(k,'.6f'))!= (format(mt.pi,'.6f'))):
    z = TaylorExp(1,i)
    i += 1
    k= z*4
print ('The value for pi found from arctan (1) is', format(k,'.6f'),' which is accurate to 7sf.')
print ('The number of iterations N required is: ',i, format(mt.pi, '.6f'))
```

It works quickly for up to 3 decimal places, but takes minutes for 4dp and hours/days for 5 and 6 dp. I understand this is a very inefficient method however having spent quite a while trying different while loops etc I cannot find a faster method using my TaylorExp function and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it somehow does not make sense that it takes that long.. Break your code down to smaller pieces to find out where the delay is coming from.

Comment: for 5 decimal places it takes a second for 1,000,000 iterations but it seems that is converging very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is taking `O(n^2)` time, as the first time, you're doing 1 iteration, the second 2, and so on.

You could change your `TaylorExp` function to instead return a generator, which yields every step of the series in order:

```
def TaylorExp(x):
    total = 0.0
    n = 0.0
    while True:
        c = (((-1)**n)/((2*n)+1))*(x**((2*n)+1))
        n += 1
        total += c
        yield total
```

And then use it like this:

```
i = 0
k = 0.0

for z in TaylorExp(1):
    k = z * 4
    if format(k, '.6f') == format(math.pi, '.6f'):
        break
    i += 1

print ('The value for pi found from arctan (1) is', format(k, '.6f'),' which is accurate to 7sf.')
print ('The number of iterations N required is: ', i, format(math.pi, '.6f'))
```

On my computer, this code takes around 5 seconds, and prints:

```
The value for pi found from arctan (1) is 3.141593  which is accurate to 7sf.
The number of iterations N required is:  1181460 3.141593
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for the help and the explanation - I understand perfectly.